# How to change node's color individually in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

In Node's Style view, if I change the color in the label setting, it changes all the color of all nodes. I want to control the color of each individual node. How can I do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches.  First, you can create a column that has the color values or categories and use a discrete mapper to map the color.  Second, you can select the nodes you want to change the label color of and then click on the third column (Byp.) rather than the first column, and that would change the label color just for those nodes.

-- scooter

Comment: So to someone who just started using the library, this doesn't really quite give much direction. Like I have no idea what a discrete mapper is?

Answer (score 2):

Select the node or nodes which you want to change color. Go to Node tab and Select>Style>Fill...click on 3rd box (bypass (Byp.)) and change color. Hope this helps.

[image]